# H2 Syntax Question For How to Define Inplicit Column Name

Tags: db2, h2

I have a SQL syntax question, in DB2, I can write such sql:

```sql
select * from 
(values(0),(1)) ones(n), 
(values(0),(1)) tens(n)
```

but in H2, it pop error: Syntax error in sql statement:

```sql
select * from 
(values(0),(1)) ones([*]n), 
(values(0),(1)) tens(n)
[42000-191] 42000/42000
```

Can anyone give hint how to write it in H2? I think it is related with how to define implicit columns on the fly.

Comment: Is there anything in the [H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#table_value) that is unclear? And why is this tagged with [db2]?

Comment: @mustaccio, the thing i am not clear is how to give column name in such case, while in DB2, i can write as (values(0),(1)) ones(n), giving column name as "n", in H2, it seems not allowable, or maybe i don't know yet

Answer (score 1):

You're using an outdated version of H2 database. This syntax is only supported since H2 1.4.197, you need to use it or some newer version.

Comment: thanks, you are right, after i upgrade to H2 1.4.200, it recoganize this syntax now.